# How to close connection of Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server, enterprise-library

I'm using the library microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary, to access a SQL Server database.
I'm wondering how to close connection when I use the ExecuteNonQuery method?

ie:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql;

SqlDatabase db = null;
try
{
    db = new SqlDatabase(stringConnection);
    db.ExecuteNonQuery("storedprocedure", someParams);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

I can't do something like

```
finally
{
    if (db != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)db).Dispose();
    }
}
```

So... how can I avoid connection leaks?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the code inside the "using" block.  This will ensure the connection closed after finishing.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql;

SqlDatabase db = new SqlDatabase(stringConnection);
using (DbConnection con = db.CreateConnection())
{
    db.ExecuteNonQuery("storedprocedure", someParams);
}
```

or you can use the con.Close().

Answer (score 5):

Generally you do not need to worry about closing the connection, as Data Access Block manages connections more efficiently. check "Managing Connections" section in below link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953187(v=pandp.50).aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("GetProductsByCategory"); 
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@requestId", DbType.Int32, requestId);
db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
```

The Enterprise Library handles closing connections for you, except for the case of using Data Readers. When using a IDataReader, you should either use the close or a using to call the dispose (same as calling close)

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

DbCommand cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand("Select Name, Address From Customers");
using (IDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(cmd))
{
   // Process results
}
```

The dispose in this case will close the connection.  They have a great section on connection handling in the documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648933.aspx