# Enterprise Library Database connection close

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, enterprise-library

> We are using Microsoft Enterprise library to access the sql server database.We are 
>       having some doubts about how to close the DB Connection.Code is given below.

```
DatabaseFactory.SetDatabaseProviderFactory(new DatabaseProviderFactory(), false);
Database db = new DatabaseProviderFactory().Create("Dataconnectionstring");
string sqlCommand = "";
DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand);
dbCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
try
{
  success = Convert.ToInt32(db.ExecuteScalar(dbCommand));
  return success;
}
  so how  can we close database connection.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473907/how-to-close-connection-of-microsoft-practices-enterpriselibrary-data-executenon

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is use `using` statements.
All Objects that are implementing `IDisposable` can be used in such way, when code reaches the closing bracket it calls `Dispose()` that is supposed to get rid of the object.

```
DatabaseFactory.SetDatabaseProviderFactory(new DatabaseProviderFactory(), false);
        int success = 0;
        using (var db = new DatabaseProviderFactory().Create("Dataconnectionstring"))
        {
            string sqlCommand = "";
            using (var dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand))
            {
                dbCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
                try
                {
                    success = Convert.ToInt32(db.ExecuteScalar(dbCommand));
                }
            }
        }

    return success;
```

Comment: Wrong! Database is not disposable.

Comment: @Emanuele Hi Emanuele, when you say database is not disposable, which object are you referring to?

Comment: I tried your code 2 days ago. I think on  using (var db = new DatabaseProviderFactory().Create("Dataconnectionstring"))

Comment: @Emanuele I would guess that `T` that `Create`   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748589(v=pandp.31).aspx returns is not `IDisposable` in your implementation..... Which usually is the case...

Comment: But we are talking of specific case about Enterprise Library. Maybe object is different from that in past years. DatabaseProviderFactory().Create("foo") create a Database object which is not disposable.